# How to calculate Recall for Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) based Recommendation System

Tags: deep-learning, recommendation-engine, recurrent-neural-network, collaborative-filtering, precision-recall

As I know, In Top-N Recommendation System, the formular of Recall is as below :

```
recall = |{A} and {B}| / |{A}|
```

**where {A} are the things that user actually bought, {B} are the Top-N things that system recommended.**

But in RNN based recommendation system, it is a  little different from the traditional recommendation system such as kNN based recommendation system (user based or item based system).

**The target of RNN based recommendation system is to predict the thing that user would probably buy in next time "t+1". In each step, system will give a Top-N recommendation.** Reference paper:[enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07400)

So how to caclulate Recall for Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) based Recommendation System?

Answer (score 0):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06939.pdf

In this paper, recall is calculated as "proportion of cases having the desired item amongst the top-k items in all test cases."

Comment: I have read this paper too. Suppose we have two sequence: [a, x, c, j, e] and [f, t, h, k, p, y], if system predict "x", "c", "e" successfully in first sequence and predict "h", "k" successfully in second sequence, the recall is calculated as this:  (3+2)/(5+6). Am I right?

Comment: I don't think there is any better explanation than adding them all.